# Does the WIX heat utility work with Visual C++ projects?

Tags: visual-c++, wix, heat

I am just starting to use Wix and would like to use heat to extract the outputs from my Visual C++ projects to source Wix files.  This seems to work great for my C# projects, however, whenever I run heat on a C++ project I get an error:

```
heat project MyProject.vcproj -pog:Binaries -cg MyGroup -nologo -out MySource.wxs
heat.exe : error HEAT5307 : Build failed.
```

Is this supposed to work or am I doing something wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Can your VS C++ project be built using MSBuild ?

Comment: Yes, I run my builds through MSBuild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in Visual Studio 2008 and earlier. C++ projects are not really MSbuild projects (just a shells around vcbuild.exe or something like that) so there is no introspection into those projects. It's quite sad.

Rumor has it that the VC++ team is fixing this in Visual Studio 2010 so hopefully things will start working there.